# VBA error 'Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignments' when running macro via custom button

Tags: vba, tabs, ribbon, ms-word, word-2007

I have a macro that I call via a tab/group/button added by the Custom UI Editor -

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="tabCustomActions" label="Custom ActionsXXX" insertAfterMso="TabDeveloper">
                <group id="GroupTLA" label="TLA Actions">
                    <button id="buttonFormatTLA" label="Format as TLA" image="TLALogo" size="large" onAction="start_tla" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

The button shows up just fine, with my custom logo, but when ever I click the button I get the follow error -

[image: VBA Error]

VBA is not opened following this error, as it usually is, and no code within VBA is indicated as the problem if I open the developer console and then try and click the button.

Strangely though, if I try and run the macro manually, it works fine with no errors. Does anybody have any ideas how to solve this?

Here is my full code in a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/H3eQ2XXQ), should you wish to view it. Thanks.

Comment: The VBA IDE doesn't open because you're not running VBA, this is a macro, right? What code is running in VBA when you 'run it manually'?

Comment: Brad: in Excel and the other office products, VBA = macro.  Same thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have the wrong call signature for the `start_tla` callback in your VBA code.

If you open up your file in *Custom UI Editor*, there is a button called **Generate Callbacks** to the right in the menu. If you press it, it will give you the correct callbacks for your VBA code to match the ribbon xml in your file:

```
'Callback for buttonFormatTLA onAction
Sub start_tla(control As IRibbonControl)
    'Your code goes here
End Sub
```

According to the Pastebin link, your sub looks like this, without the `control As IRibbonControl` parameter:

```
Public Sub start_tla()
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that. I actually created a generic `on_customUI_action` callback function and then checked which button was pressed. That way the macro works if I run it manually also. Thanks.

Comment: In my case, I had the same module name in another `Add-In` that was open. This error has gone after I gave unique name to the module.

Answer (score 0):

It is old thread, but maybe it will help someone.
If you make 'control' argument optional, you can run either from Ribbon button or directly from VBA or Form button.

```
Sub start_tla(Optional control As IRibbonControl)
    'Your code goes here
End Sub
```